# How do I deserialize a Map<?, ?> containing a List<?> as a value...e.g. Map<Long, List<Long>?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a Map<Long, List> using jackson.  I'm getting a compile time error when I'm trying to call the deserialization method.  The mapper I'm using is the  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.  I have included the following code below:  The Mapper initialization, the deserialization method, the JUnit test that is causing the compile type error and the actual error iteself.

```
//. ObjectMapper initialization
    public static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
      .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
      .addModule(new SimpleModule()
          .addAbstractTypeMapping(Claims.class, DefaultClaims.class)
          .addAbstractTypeMapping(GrantedAuthority.class, SimpleGrantedAuthority.class)
      )
      .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
      .addMixIn(PersonTraits.class, PersonTraitsMixIn.class)
      .addMixIn(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class, SimpleGrantedAuthorityMixin.class)
      .build();
```

Deserialization method:

```
    `public static <K, V, T extends Map<?, ?>> Map<K, List<V>> deserializeMap(String` genericObject, Class<T> mapClass,
              Class<K> keyClass, Class<List<V>> valueClass) throws Exception {
            if (genericObject == null) {
              return null;
            }
            try {
              return objectMapper.readValue(genericObject, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(mapClass, keyClass, valueClass));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              //. Do something
              throw e;
            }
          }
```

JUnit test case:

```
      @Test
      public void testDeserializeMapContainingListAsValue() throws Exception {
        // given
        Map<Long, List<Long>> mapToSerialize = new HashMap<>();
        List<Long> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        valueList.add(2L);
        mapToSerialize.put(1L, valueList);
        String serializedMap = SerializationUtil.serializeObject(mapToSerialize);
    
        // when
        final Map<Long, List<Long>> result = SerializationUtil.deserializeMap(serializedMap, HashMap.class, Long.class,
            List.class);
    
        // then
        assertNotNull(result);
      }

The when statement is throwing the error:
 

     // when
            final Map<Long, List<Long>> result = SerializationUtil.deserializeMap(serializedMap1, HashMap.class, Long.class,
                List.class);

    The error says:  
    
                 Required type.      Provided
    mapClass:    Class<T>.           Class<HashMap>
    keyClass:    Class<K>            Class<Long>
    valueClass:  Class<List<V>>.     Class<List>
    reason: Incompatible equality constraint: List<V> and List
```

Does anyone know whats going on and how to fix it?  I apologize if there is an obvious problem in the code above that I am missing.  I'm fairly new to programming.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks all and take care!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know whats going on?

Generic type information is lost at runtime due to [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) so the `V` in `List<V>` is not available at runtime.

You can extend Jackson's `TypeReference` to maintain the type information at runtime.

```java
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
Type valueType = (new TypeReference<List<Long>>() {}).getType();
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, Long.class, valueType);
Map<Long, List<Long>> map = (Map) objectMapper.readValue(json, mapType);
```

Or more simply

```java
Map<Long, List<Long>> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<Long, List<Long>>() {});
```

Comment: The method return type already is `Map<K, List<V>>` for a `Class<V>` and `Class<V>`. Sandeep isn't wrapping the `Class<V>` in a list type though. There is no need for a `TypeReference` or `LongList`.

Comment: With `List<V>` the `V` is lost due to [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) (eg `V` is not available at runtime) so you need some way of holding the generic list type at runtime. `TypeReference` allows for this to be kept at runtime since a new class object is created (by extending `TypeReference`)

Comment: You didn't read my comment correctly. The class object that's given is not the map's value type but the list element type. The return type is not `Map<K, V>` but `Map<K, List<V>>`, and `Class<K>` and `Class<V>` are given.

Comment: Well... in the test it's passing `List.class`  - `SerializationUtil.deserializeMap(serializedMap, HashMap.class, Long.class, List.class)`. Regardless my solution still stands. I see your solution with `constructCollectionType` would also work

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `constructMapType` with the given value type, but it should be a constructed list type with the given value type as element type. Right now you want a `Map<K, List<V>>` but are asking Jackson to deserialize to a `Map<K, V>`.

You'd need the following:

```java
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
return objectMapper.readValue(genericObject, typeFactory.constructMapType(mapClass,
        typeFactory.constructType(keyClass),
        typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, valueClass)));
```